# Visual Studio Solution(.sln) / C#: Start a project with another project's dll as parameter

Tags: c#, visual-studio

**is it possible to run a project with an argument of a dll from another project?**

My project structure and dependencies look like this

[image]
[image]

As you can see there are no direct dependencies between a mod and the game implementation directly.

When I click on `Debug -> Start New Instance`, `F5` or use the button ([image]) I want to run `./ExampleGameInEngineA.exe GameModC.dll`.

I know that you can set an `Executable` in the project settings
[image]

But I am looking for a more generic way that is automatically compiling `ExampleGameInEngineA` and putting it in the same directory as `GameModC`.
Hardcoded directory paths are also not great (tho I could use relative paths for this).

For testing purposes we can safely ignore `GameInEngineB` but I still don't want any hard references to `GameInEngineA`.

Comment: You can specify the output path in the Build properties, e.g. all projects could build into the same directory

Comment: I would like to separate the resulting output for each project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I kinda solved it by myself by using a PreBuild-Event-Target:

`GameModC.csproj`

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>netstandard2.1</TargetFramework>
        <AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>false</AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>
        <RunPostBuildEvent>OnOutputUpdated</RunPostBuildEvent>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <Target Name="PreBuild" BeforeTargets="PreBuildEvent" Condition="">
        <MSBuild Projects="$(SolutionDir)ExampleGameInEngineA\ExampleGameInEngineA.csproj..." />
        <ItemGroup>
            <GameEngineAOutputFolder Include="$(SolutionDir)ExampleGameInEngineA\$(OutDir)*.*" />
        </ItemGroup>
        <Copy SourceFiles="@(GameEngineAOutputFolder)" DestinationFolder="$(OutDir)" SkipUnchangedFiles="false" />
    </Target>

    <ItemGroup>
      <ProjectReference Include="..\GameApi\GameModdingApi.csproj" />
    </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

`GameInEngineA.csproj`

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
        <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
        <AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>false</AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <ProjectReference Include="..\GameApi\GameModdingApi.csproj" />
    </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Please note the `AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath` to remove the `netcoreapp3.1` or `netstandard2.1`.

But there are still problems with the solution:

- It does not recognize changes made in `ExampleGameInEngineA` (manual rebuild required)
- The `Condition` when to add `ExampleGameInEngineA` is always met (because I have no good idea for a condition)

I am still open for better solutions.

Comment: It might be easier to do this with tools like Cake or Nuke.